# Loops in PHP to repeat incrementing value over array

Tags: php, loops

I am having an issue where I create a loop of headings. I want to create a list of dates for each heading, these dates are pulled from MySQL as are the headings.

I think I am looking to loop within an loop.

I think once `$h` reaches `$number_of_days` it doesn’t reset even though it is within the 1st `while` loop. Is there a different way to go about this?

```
$h='1';
          while($report_types = $rt_type->fetch())
            {


$rt_types = $report_types['report_name'];
            echo '<div>'. $rt_types .'</div>';


while($h <= $number_of_days){          
            echo '<div class="report_day">'.$h.'</div>';
            $h++;

            }    
        }
```

Comment: `while($h <= $number_of_days){` where did you initialize $h?

Comment: `$h='1';` should be `$h=1;` to make it an integer.

Comment: @Biotox should be; but probably doesn't cause a problem.  `<=` will do a loose comparison casting `$h`, and then `$h++` will cast to an integer.

Comment: Other than the fact that $h='1' should be $h=1 what is the value of $number_of_days and where is it set?

Comment: What i see is that you don't need that while() loop. For example `for($h=1;$h<=$number_of_days;$h++) {` will end all `$h` issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a reset to `$h` before the next loop of `$report_types`

```
    $h=1;
    while($report_types = $rt_type->fetch())
    {
        $rt_types = $report_types['report_name'];
        echo '<div>'. $rt_types .'</div>';


        while($h <= $number_of_days){          
            echo '<div class="report_day">'.$h.'</div>';
            $h++;
        }

        $h=1; //RESET BEFORE NEXT LOOP
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `$h='1';` inside the first while.

So change:

```
$h='1';
while($report_types = $rt_type->fetch())
{
```

into:

```
while($report_types = $rt_type->fetch())
{
    $h='1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of problem with your code is coming from formatting more than anything. The less readable code is, the harder it is to debug.

That said, here is my reworked version of your code:

```
while($report_types = $rt_type->fetch()) {
  $rt_types = $report_types['report_name'];
  echo '<div>' . $rt_types . '</div>';
  for ($h = 1; $h <= $number_of_days; $h++) {
    echo '<div class="report_day">' . $h . '</div>';
  }
}
```

What I did is remove the `while` loop & switched it to `for` loop which makes the logic a bit cleaner. So now your `$h1` incrementing logic is all contained in this one line `for ($h = 1; $h <= $number_of_days; $h++) {` which makes it all easier to read & understand as well.

Also, as far as your original code goes, this assignment to `$h` is problematic:

```
$h='1';
```

When you place a value in quotes like that it makes the contents within those quotes a literal string. For numerical purposes like this you would set that as:

```
$h=1;
```